# How to make ALPHANUMERIC constraint in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, tabs

doing my assignment on Databases. Working with MySQL, my task is to create database with several tables. One of them is the table of workers in which primary key is WId, which is the String of 16 A-Z and 0-9 elements. I need to make a constraint such that it is not possible to put there !@#$%^ etc.

```
create table Worker (   WId     char(16) primary key,
                        Name    char(10),
                        Surname char(20),...);
```

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL does not support check constraints, so you would need to use a trigger.

Comment: Ok, thanks, could you show please how to check it with the trigger?

Comment: @TeamBeam SO is not a code-writing service. Do your own research, and post what you tried if you can't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the `SIGNAL` keyword to return an error:

**EDIT 1**:
Based on @Gordon_linoff comment: you would have to do both `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` in case if you expect the Id to change.

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON worker
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NOT (NEW.WId REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$')
   THEN
      BEGIN      
        SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'TADA!';
      END;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You should probably have an `update` trigger as well.

Comment: @TeamBeam please consider closing the question if it satisfies your needs